# What does the $(this) represent for in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to build up a simple star rate render function by github.com/wbotelhos/raty.
It would transfer the "scores" of data attributes to stars.

**HTML**

```
<div class="score_show" data-scores="4"></div>
<div class="score_show" data-scores="2"></div>
```

**JS**

Method1 failed

```
$('.score_show').raty({ readOnly: true,score: $(this).data('scores')});
```

The method failed,so I try another method.

Method2 works

```
  $('.score_show').each(function(){
   var score=$(this).data('scores');
   $(this).raty({ readOnly: true,score: score});
  })
```

I thought the problem in method1 is that the $(this) did not represent for the correct element.But could someone give me an more detailed explain about the reason method1 failed?
Thanks.

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Comment: the current object ..in this case a div

Comment: Thanks,but why does the method1 fail if the $(this) represent for the current div dom?

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, `$(this)` means nothing but a method call - it calls a method named `$()` and passes the object referred by the keyword `this`.

When you talk about in the context of jQuery, `$` refers to the jQuery library and that method returns a [jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) which refers to the dom elements referred by the argument passed.

In your case you want to get the data-score values from the `score_show` objects... so first you need to get a reference to those objects to fetch the data value.

In your first sample, `this` might be referring different object(we can't say much about it without knowing where it is placed and how that script is invoked)

But in your second sample you are calling `$('.score_show')` which will return a jQuery object which contains all the elements with the class `score_show` and when you use .each() it iterates through each of those elements and calls the callback method passed to `.each()`. Inside the each callback `this` refers to the dom element which is currently being iterated through so you can get the data-score attribute of that element by using `$(this).data('scores')`

Answer (score 1):

in you case ,$(this) means current looping div object..you can use console.log($(this)) to see what it is..

Answer (score 0):

`this` in javascript usually refer to the object that invoked the current function.

Inside the `.each()`, `this` represents the current iterated DOM object

`$(this)` is just used to wraps the DOMElement in a jQuery object so you can apply jQuery method on `this`.