# What does do the $(@) in CoffeesScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Simple question,
What does do the following line:

```
$(@)
```

in CoffeeScript ?

Comment: may be useful furher reading regarding jQuery `$(this)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@` is an alias for `this`.

So it calls the `$` function (which may, or not, be jQuery depending on the rest of your code) with `this` as argument.