# Using jQuery $(this) with .on();

Tags: jquery

I'm building a plugin to submit forms with jQuery.

It needs to work with live elements, so I need to use `$(document).on();`

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$.fn.submittable = function() {
  $(document).on('submit', this, function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //Do whatever
  });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tosubmit').submittable();
});
```

But `$(this)` doesn't seem to work with `.on()`

if I do, `$(this).submit(function(event) {});` it works fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to understand what `this` is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Comment: I have, that also didn't seem to work.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't think that question is relevant here. In the context of a plugin, `this` is the jQuery object, not the DOM element

Comment: `$(this).submit(function(event) {});` if this works fine then use it, why looking for event delegation?

Comment: @Jai as a matter of principle I recommend that modern jQuery code should _always_ use `.on()` for event registration, and the appropriate `.trigger` call for event simulation.  Having the same method (e.g. `.click`) do both is a recipe for confusion.

Comment: I've been thinking the same. Why do not all the functions, e.g. click, submit, hover use the .on(); functionality?

Comment: I mean, the default. You have to specify `.on();` which is confusing.

Comment: using `this` as the delegate target makes no sense, if you have access to `this`, why do you need delegation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I explained the issue well enough. The replies to this question suggested this was bad practice, and I was not sure why. However I just found the solution and all is now clear to me.

When using plugins with live content, the plugin must be loaded inside the `$.post` or `.get` function like so.

```
$.post('.').done(function(data) {
  $('.to-call-on').plugin();
});
```

Comment: So in other words you had an X/Y problem. Instead of asking how to apply plugins to dynamic elements, you asked how to use `this` with .on for delegation, which is confusing because knowing what that syntax does makes using it that way not make sense. However, i'm glad you found the correct way of fixing it.

Comment: Yup, that's what I told you to do: _"just invoke that on your newly-loaded content after each AJAX call."_

Comment: Ya, thanks for the help. I see now that I was an ignoramus, and should have looked closer at what you posted which was in fact so very clear.

Answer (score 3):

The delegated version of `.on` requires that the `selector` parameter be a string, not an element (or in your case, a jQuery object, that being what `this` is within a jQuery plugin).

Why use delegation at all, though?

```
$.fn.submittable = function() {
    return this.on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ...
    });
};
```

and then just invoke that on your newly-loaded content after each AJAX call.

Comment: The op said that it has to work with live elements, which supposedly is elements that are added dynamically. If so, that's why delegation is used.

Comment: I'm building an AJAX web application in which most of the forms are live. Also, pretty much every form is submitted through AJAX. I found myself writing a function for every form. This is so all I need to do to "AJAX" a form, is add a class and call the plugin.

Comment: @Guffa I missed the "live" part, but IMHO no plugin should automatically attach itself to elements not yet created.  When the elements are created (which must surely be under the programmer's control) then the plugin should be invoked.

Comment: @Guffa the corollary of that is that if the plugin is not specific to a particular element then perhaps it shouldn't be a `$.fn` plugin at all.

Comment: I spoke too soon, when the form is on a page loaded with jQuery, through `.post();`, this does not work. What exactly is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `selector` property to get the selector that was used to create the jQuery object:

```
$.fn.submittable = function() {
  $(document).on('submit', this.selector, function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //Do whatever
  });
};
```

Note: This makes your plugin work in the way that the jQuery `live` method did. That way of binding events was abandoned because the syntax is a bit awkward and can cause confusion. You should consider using a syntax more like the one the `on` method uses for delegation:

```
$.fn.submittable = function(selector) {
  this.on('submit', selector, function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //Do whatever
  });
};
```

Usage example:

```
$(document).submittable('.tosubmit');
```

Comment: `.selector` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 !

Comment: @Alnitak: That doesn't mean that it's gone. Anyhow, I also added an alternative syntax that doesn't use the `selector` property.

Comment: I see your reasoning in using selector as a variable, and that does work. However I am not keen on using a plugin this way, I would rather do `$('.tosubmit').submittable();` Is there a way to do that with this method?

Comment: @Palmer: No, then you need to use the first approach. If you want to specify the selector by creating a jQuery object with it, then you have to dig the selector out of the jQuery object.

Comment: @Palmer strictly speaking you're abusing the plugin mechanism. The element on which a `$.fn.foo` is invoked must (albeit only by convention) _always_ already exist, even in a delegated `.on` call.  FWIW, I'm not sure what you're trying to do would even work with a delegated call, some answers here say that on some browsers the `submit` event doesn't bubble.

Comment: How should I go about this then?