# Differences between "this" in Javascript and in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

To my knowledge, the `this` keyword [refers to the `window` object in Javascript](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/). However, while working through the [codecademy jQuery track](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-GfjC6/1/5?curriculum_id=50a3fad8c7a770b5fd0007a1), it says "the `this` keyword refers to the object you're currently doing something with" like the button being clicked clicked etc.

Are these two facts reconcilable as two sides of the same coin, or is the implementation of the `this` keyword truly different between JS and jQuery?

Comment: no... the value of `this` differ based on the context of its use...

Comment: in jquery `$(this)` is the context of your selected html element, wrapped in `$()` so that you can use the jquery api on it

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this