# .html() is not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery

I'm wasting some hours to find solution, I can't find it...

Here is my code :

```
$(".usefull").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fbkId = $(this).find(".glyphicon").data("id");
    $(this).parent().html('<a href="#" class="btn btn-grey usefull disabled"><img src="/www/images/mini-loader.gif" alt="" /> Est utile</a>');
    var that = this;
    $.post('{{ route("www-ajax-feedback-add-usefull") }}',{ fbkId: fbkId },
            function(data) {
                if (data == '1') {
                    toastr.success('Merci pour votre contribution !');
                    $(that).parent().html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up disabled"></i> Est utile</a>');

                } else {
                    toastr.error(data);
                }
            }
    );
    return false;
});
```

When I click on a button, I update the button with loading gif.

When my ajax call is finish, I want to update the state button, but it's not working.

Thanks for help

Here it is more informations :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-grey agree"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" data-id="2161"></i> Je suis d'accord</a>
```

If I put console.log($(that).html()); after $.post here it output :
`<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" data-id="2161"></i> Je suis d'accord`

Comment: what is "that"?? $(that).parent().html(...) , is it "this"?

Comment: seems your HTML is incorrect in `html()` call ...

Answer (score 0):

For any elements which will get binding to the DOM through ajax or added at run time, you have to use

```
http://api.jquery.com/live/
```

or delegates

```
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
```

Those will be binded at the document level.

Comment: I tried with $(".usefull").on("click", function(){ (live is depreciated and "delegate" and "on" are same). It's not working

Comment: Then try using `.done(function() {` and see if it goes in that block or not, reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Thanks for advises, yes it goes in, but the $(this).parent().html still does not work

Answer (score 0):

==>`this` reference a javascript object and `$(this)` used to encapsulate with jQuery.

```
$(".usefull").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fbkId = $(this).find(".glyphicon").data("id");
    $(this).parent().html('<a href="#" class="btn btn-grey usefull disabled"><img src="/www/images/mini-loader.gif" alt="" /> Est utile</a>');
    var that = $(this);
   // use $(this); insetd of this;

    $.post('{{ route("www-ajax-feedback-add-usefull") }}',{ fbkId: fbkId },
            function(data) {
                if (data == '1') {
                    toastr.success('Merci pour votre contribution !');
                    $(that).parent().html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up disabled"></i> Est utile</a>');

                } else {
                    toastr.error(data);
                }
            }
    );
    return false;
});
```

read more at 
[jQuery: What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

Comment: I just replace like you advised it's still same problem

Comment: are you sure that your ajax function is done sucessfully please check browser console if u have any error

Comment: Yes it's done, I saw message trought toastr and have no error

Comment: Il would say that it's not still working but I have no error in console