# How to target an element using "this" keyword?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail-container">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1024x768" alt="...">
            <div class="thumbnail-overlay"></div>
            <p class="text-center text-nowrap" style="display:block">title</p>
        </div>
    </div>

function overlay () {
    $('.thumbnail-container > .text-center').mouseenter(function () {
        $('.thumbnail-container > .thumbnail-overlay').fadeOut(500)
    })
    $('.thumbnail-container > .text-center').mouseleave(function () {
        $('.thumbnail-container > .thumbnail-overlay').fadeIn(500)
    })
}
```

I have 6 of those `"thumbnail-container"` and I'd like to execute that jquery code only when a single of them is hovered (obviously). Right now when i hover a `"p.text-center"` the code fades out ALL the divs in ALL the `6` containers. I've tried putting the `"this"` keyword anywhere but it still not working.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right `this`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Comment: Within the `mouseenter` callback, `this` represents the `.text-center` element that was hovered. You'll need to select the parent `.thumbnail-container` from that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event handler is on a `.text-center`, but the element you want to fade out is its sibling with `.thumbnail-overlay`, so you could do this:

```
$(this).siblings('.thumbnail-overlay').fadeOut(500)
```

Comment: yep. that's it. thanks. also jbarnett solution works but yours is less typing

Answer (score 2):

```
function overlay () {
    $('.thumbnail-container > .text-center').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.thumbnail-overlay').fadeOut(500)
    });
    $('.thumbnail-container > .text-center').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.thumbnail-overlay').fadeIn(500)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="text-center text-nowrap" style="display:block" mouseenter="fade_out(this)" mouseleave="fade_in(this)">title</p>
```

and

```
function fade_in(element){
    $(element).fadeIn(500);
}

function fade_out(element){
    $(element).fadeOut(500);
}
```