# $(this) keyword on jQuery

Tags: jquery

Trying to understand how the *this* keyword works. For example on this code, *this* is refering to "button" right? (or to the action of clicking the button). 
Thank you

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").on("click", function(){
    var discount = $(this).closest(".tour").data("discount");
    var message = $("<span>Call 1-555-jquery-air for a $discount discount.</span>");
    $(this).closest(".tour").append(message);
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

HTML here:

```
<div id="tours">
  <h1>Guided Tours</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="usa tour" data-discount="299">
      <h2>New York, New York</h2>
      <span class="details">$1,899 for 7 nights</span>
      <button class="book">Book Now</button>
    </li>
    <li class="europe tour" data-discount="176">
      <h2>Paris, France</h2>
      <span class="details">$2,299 for 7 nights</span>
      <button class="book">Book Now</button>
    </li>
    <li class="asia tour" data-discount="349">
      <h2>Tokyo, Japan</h2>
      <span class="details">$3,799 for 7 nights</span>
      <button class="book">Book Now</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this)` indeed refers to the button.

Comment: It's discussed at length in several places. Here's the unencapsulated "this" in the offical jquery docs: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/ there's also this post that elaborates on it a bit: https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified and here's a SO question about the difference between $(this) and this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that code, `this` is a reference to the element that was clicked (the actual DOM `button` element). `$(this)` is a *function call*, passing `this` into `$()` and getting back a jQuery object. That jQuery object is a wrapper around the DOM element.

So that code is repeatedly calling `$()` with the same argument. It's not particularly harmful, in that context, but if you were in a tight loop or something, you'd want to call it *once* and keep a reference to the result.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, as in most object-oriented programming languages, `this` is a special keyword that is used in methods to refer to the object on which a method is being invoked. The value of `this` is determined using a simple series of steps:

- If the function is invoked using `Function.call()` or `Function.apply()`, `this` will be set to the first argument passed to `.call()`/`.apply()`. If the first argument passed to `.call()`/`.apply()` is `null` or `undefined`, `this` will refer to the global object (which is the `window` object in web browsers).
- If the function being invoked was created using `Function.bind()`, `this` will be the first argument that was passed to `.bind()` at the time the function was created.
- If the function is being invoked as a method of an object, `this` will refer to that object.
- Otherwise, the function is being invoked as a standalone function not attached to any object, and `this` will refer to the global object.

Reference to [this URL](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Comment: seems a bit high level for what OP is asking. Does it really answer the question and specific use case?

Comment: The question is absolutely answered by this... "If the function is being invoked as a method of an object, `this` will refer to that object." It may be a bit high level, but I don't know @vsl0610, and they may completely comprehend all of this, then again, they may not. In which case this can be helpful knowledge for them going into the future.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the this keyword is similarly used to refer to an object that the function (where this is used) is bound to. The this keyword not only refers to the object but it also contains the value of the object.