# How to make "this" refer to the element firing the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to make "this" refer to the element which is actually firing the event:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon header-text" id="action-header-text">Action</span>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="action-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" style="min-width:250px;">
            <span class=" caret">
            </span>
        </button>
        <ul id="action-menu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Filling Ajax Request:

```
function UpdateActionDropdown() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'FrontEnd/Action',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            lid: document.getElementById('selected-language-id').value
        },
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById('action-dropdown').firstChild.data = data.UnSelectable[0].ActionTrailer.DescriptionText;
            $('#action-menu').html(null);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.UnSelectable.length; i++) {
                $('#action-menu').append("<li role='presentation' class='disabled'><a role='menuitem' tabindex='-1'>" + data.UnSelectable[i].ActionTrailer.DescriptionText + "</a></li>")
            }
            $('#action-menu').append("<li role='presentation' class='divider'></li>");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Selectable.length; i++) {
                $('#action-menu').append("<li role='presentation'>" +
                    "<a role='menuitem' tabindex='-1' text='" + data.Selectable[i].DescriptionText + "' value='" + data.Selectable[i].ActionTrailer.ID + "'\" href='#'>" + data.Selectable[i].ActionTrailer.DescriptionText + "</a></li>")
            }
        }
    });
}
```

global listener:

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', '#action-menu li', function(){
    // Inside here I want to access the li-element which got clicked.
});
```

I assume that "this" inside the onclick Handler would refer to the document (or window) itself - is it possible to refer to the actual event firing element?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `this` refers to element which invoke the event

Comment: So you just didn't test it?!....??? But this is kind of good question

Comment: You can get the target element using `target` property in the `event`

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu It won't be necessary the LI element and more often it would be one of its children, unlike `event.currentTarget`  https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

Comment: you need to do something like this:onclick="click(this)" and in your function something like this function click(arg)

Comment: @Satpal, you have a point. But will this(the javascript version) **always** be the invoking element?

Comment: @AmmarCSE of course, `$(this)` is just `this` wrapped in jq object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `$(this)` which will be a `DOM`(in the context of jQuery) element when you are in a callback function

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', '#action-menu li', function(){
    $(this)// It will be the li element clicked
});
```

See [jQuery: What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this) and https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified

Comment: I already tested but $(this).value will always be 0 - but none of my li-elements got this value - so I assume that $(this) is refering to the document instead of the <li> element. Is there any way to prove this?

Comment: @Chill-X, use $(this).val()

Comment: `this.value` or `$(this).val()` but not `$(this).value. That's said, LI element has no property value (by default)`

Comment: @Chill-X, use $(this).text()

Comment: @A.Wolff both of the possible notations will result in 0 - the "global listener" lies inside <script>-Tags at the bottom of my page - hope you guys noticed that. Does that change anything?

Comment: @AmmarCSE seems like .text() works - but why doesn't value return the (self created) value-property? I saved the ID from the Database inside this value-attribute - I really depend on that...

Comment: @Chill-X How do you check it? Post minimalistic sample showing this behaviour. And `value` isn't valid attribute for LI element, you should use `data-*` instead, e.g: `data-value` even `data-id` seems more relevant

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you! I've never heard about data-* so I think I have to read a few articles about this before I'm able to continue working on my project. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @A.Wolff sorry for using this post again but - more or less it's the same issue - I think. Now I set data-value to contain the database id - but trying to access $(this).data("value").val() results in a null reference exception.

Comment: @Chill-X, I think $(this).data('value') without the .val() will work

Comment: @AmmarCSE no, alert($(this).data('value')) will return a dialog box containing "undefined". (every <li> element got a data-value between 1 and 4).

Comment: @Chill-X, can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: @Chill-X `return a dialog box` How that? How do you set it? Again: `Post minimalistic sample showing this behaviour.`

Comment: @Chill-X `this` in your jsFiddle refers to A element, which has no `data-value` set. Here is your updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ezvsmgtu/6/ or bind click event to LI level: https://jsfiddle.net/ezvsmgtu/7/

Comment: obviously a 'self-made' mistake - a great thank you for you :)

Comment: I'm so sorry but it doesn't work as expected - even after your hard work... Here's a more accurate jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ezvsmgtu/10/

Comment: @Chill-X, use find() to select the 'a' with the attribute  https://jsfiddle.net/ezvsmgtu/11/