# Error in event handler: "this.data() is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML list of links with `data-…` attributes on each one:

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li><a data-info="link1"> **** </a></li>
    <li><a data-info="link2">****</a></li>
    <li><a data-info="link3">**** </a></li>
    <li><a data-info="link4">****</a> </li>
</ul>
```

I need to receive the `data-info` value of a link whenever it is clicked. So I thought something like this:

```js
var my_links = $('#list').find('a');

my_links.on('click', function(){
     console.log(this.data(info));
});
```

But then I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.data is not a function

If I just do:

```js
var my_links = $('#list').find('a');

my_links.on('click', function(){
  console.log(this);
});
```

I get the complete HTML code of each link, for example:

```
<a data-info="link1"> **** </a>
```

Why are both things happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `this` in the context of the click event is an anchor tag. Anchor tags don't have a `.data()` function. You'll need to wrap it in the jQuery context `$(this)` to have access to the `.data()` function...

Comment: Protip: inside the handler, at the end, write `debugger;`. Then open up the developer tools and trigger the event. When the JS evaluation pauses inspect the actual values (eg. in the console). Fix the problem using this information.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`data()` is a jQuery method, not a method of native DOM objects.

`this` will be the `<a>` element that was clicked — a native DOM object ([`HTMLAnchorElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement)). Give it a jQuery wrapper to call jQuery methods:

```
my_links.on('click', function() {
  console.log( $(this).data('info') );
});
```

Alternatively, you can skip the jQuery wrapper and access the data attribute directly:

```
my_links.on('click', function() {
  console.log( this.dataset.info );
});
```

```js
const my_links = $('#list a');

my_links.on('click', function() {
  console.log( 'jQuery: ' + $(this).data('info') );
  console.log( 'Vanilla JS: ' + this.dataset.info );
});
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

li {
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
    <li><a data-info="link1">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-info="link2">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-info="link3">link 3</a></li>
    <li><a data-info="link4">link 4</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use $(this).data() instead of this.data().

```
var my_links = $('#list').find('a');
    my_links.on('click', function(){
        console.log($(this).data());
    });
```

Find more info on jQuery $(this) here: [jQuery: What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)