# jquery plugin css opacity

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a simple jquery plugin for a CRT type effect. I did check the documentation -> https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/ but i think i don't understand.

When i execute the code without turning it into a plugin it works fine.

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('#wallpaper').css("filter", "opacity("+ String(Math.random() * (0.96 - 1.0) + 0.96 ) +")");
}, (Math.random() * (500 - 1000) + 100) );
```

When i turn it into a plugin it does nothing.

```
$.fn.crt = function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $(this).css("filter", "opacity("+ String(Math.random() * (0.96 - 1.0) + 0.96 ) +")");
  }, (Math.random() * (500 - 1000) + 100) );
}
console.log($('#wallpaper').crt());
```

When i change `$(this).css()...` to `this.css()...` it gives me the following error : `TypeError: this.css is not a function`

Can anyone tell me how to get this code working in a plugin or what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Comment: Because of scope. `console.log(this);`

Comment: So it should be $(this). That does not answer the second part of the problem which i don't understand, and which is not explained in the question you are referring to. Thank you for clearing up one part.

Comment: Edit: I should read better. My apologied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the timeout is not what you think it is. It will be the window object. You need to either [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the anonymous function to this or use the classical closure technique of defining a variable outside.

```
$.fn.crt = function(){
  var that = $(this);
  setInterval(function(){
    that.css("filter", "opacity("+ String(Math.random() * (0.96 - 1.0) + 0.96 ) +")");
  }, (Math.random() * (500 - 1000) + 100) );
}
```