# jquery td.remove() works but td.empty() gives error

Tags: jquery

The following jquery code works, but if I change td.remove() to td.empty() I get the error message: Uncaught TypeError: td.empty is not a function

I want to empty the contents of the td rather than remove the td so I can potentially put some different text in there later. How can I do that?

```
$('.msg-delete').click(function () {
    var id = this.getAttribute("data-id");
    var td = this.closest("td");
    if (id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/messages/' + id,
            success: function () {
                td.remove();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

The table I am working on looks like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>
            <button type="button" class="close msg-delete" data-id="5">&times;</button>
           <label>From:</label> Joe &nbsp;<label><br/>a test message
         </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Note: I also tried changing this.closest("td") to $(this)[0].closest("td") with the same result.

Comment: See [jQuery $(this) vs this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

Comment: thanks @showdev  I actually read that but perhaps my remaining confusion is around I seem to need $(this).closest("td") but $(this)[0].getAttribute("data-id") why do I need [0] on getAttribute but not closest?

Comment: [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) is a native JavaScript method, while [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is a jQuery method.

Comment: aha! thanks @showdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest()` and `empty()` are both jQuery methods so you need:

```
var td = $(this).closest("td")
```

And

```
td.empty();
```

Comment: Perhaps my confusion is around I seem to need $(this).closest("td") but $(this)[0].getAttribute("data-id")  why do I need [0] on getAttribute but not closest?

Comment: `$(this)[0]` is the same as `this` ... it is the actual dom element, not a jQuery object. You are mixing jQuery and native methods. Better to stick to one or the other like `var id = $(this).data("id");`