# What does "this" word do in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, here is the question

I can not undestand when i should use "this" instead class or id

If u can show example - it will be fantastic

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code samples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Comment: no code, i wanted to have some theoretical knowledge, thank you for refer

Comment: [this keyword](https://github.com/vasanthk/js-bits/blob/master/js/this-keyword.js)

Comment: `this` belongs to current object, `this` belongs to object in a context.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can not undestand when i should use "this" instead class or id

**Usually**, you do that when you want to refer to the element on which an event was triggered from within the event handler:

```
$(".foo").on("click", function() {
    var $el = $(this);           // `this` is the element that was clicked,
                                 // so `$(this)` gives you a jQuery wrapper
                                 // around just that one element.
                                 // But $(".foo") would give you a wrapper
                                 // around **all** .foo elements, not just the
                                 // one that was clicked.
    // ...
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$(".foo").on("click", function() {
  var $el = $(this); // `this` is the element that was clicked
  $el.text("You've clicked this one");
});
```

```html
<div class="foo">Not clicked yet</div>
<div class="foo">Not clicked yet</div>
<div class="foo">Not clicked yet</div>
<div class="foo">Not clicked yet</div>
<div class="foo">Not clicked yet</div>
<div class="foo">Not clicked yet</div>
<div class="foo">Not clicked yet</div>
<div class="foo">Not clicked yet</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Sometimes, it comes up when using either `each` or `$.each`, because jQuery calls the callback to each of those methods with `this` referring to the element for that call:

```
$(".foo").each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);               // `this` is the element for this callback
    // ...
});
```

The jQuery API documentation will tell you when it's going to set `this` to a specific value in a callback.

Comment: but we can use var $el = $(.foo) too,  right?

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов: Only if you want `$el` to refer to **all** `.foo` elements, instead of the specific one that was clicked.

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов T.J said it well, you just have to read carefully, Yes you can assign `$el = $(".myEl")`, but **within** a callback function (inside a jQuery's Method callback) you refer using `$(this)` to the element who registered (triggered) such bound event / Method. If your element is already assigned to `$el` noone stops you to use that variable instead.