# Get height ul first

Tags: jquery, height

I´m using `$(this).find("ul").filter(":first").height();` to get first ul.

But the height is not defined, then the height is -20

My ul:

```
ul style="width: 252px; min-width: 820px; padding-bottom: 20px;" class="jqx-tree-dropdown-root"
```

Best Regards.

Comment: how are you getting negative height?

Comment: can you reproduce it in snippet? also share what `this` context refers to?

Comment: Is the element visible? Is the element rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I created a quick jsFiddle which displays rather well that your code should work just fine. However you are probably using "this" incorrectly :)

https://jsfiddle.net/qoxub22u/

Html mockup

```
<div class="container">
  <h5>First one has height of 40px</h5>
  <ul style="height:40px">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
  </ul>

  <h5>Second one has height of 70px</h5>
  <ul style="height:70px">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test2</li>
    <li>Test3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="submit">Get height</button>
```

Jquery part

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function() {

    /* Replace .container with ur this selector */
  var height = $('.container').find("ul").filter(":first").height();

  alert(height);
});
```

Comment: $(this) is a div.

$(this) is the same:

var self = $(this); alert(self.find("ul").filter(":first").height());

The UL height is not defined.

Comment: It seems like you don't very clearly understand how $(this) works. It's rather well explained in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Comment: Hi, this is not problem.
My code:

var treeViews = $(selector).find(".treeview");
treeViews.each(function () {
        var self = $(this);
 alert(self.find("ul").filter(":first").height());
}

Answer (score 0):

$(this) is a div.

$(this) is the same:

var self = $(this);
  alert(self.find("ul").filter(":first").height());

The UL height is not defined.