# What is the difference between $ , this and $(this) in javascript fundamentals?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between **$ , this and $(this)** in javascript fundamentals?

Also I want to know about their usage

Comment: Are you sure? This is not a duplicate of the question imo @Rayon

Comment: @eisbehr – In what context ? How ?

Comment: Question is about `$` vs `$(this)`, duplicate about `this` vs `$(this)`. That's a difference. @Rayon

Comment: @eisbehr – Are you trying to say that `$` and `$(this)` or `this` are somehow related ? Could we compare `$` with `this` or `$(this)` ?

Comment: Exactly this is the point. `$(this)` and `this` can be compared, because these both references a DOM object, one of them wrapped by jQuery object. So this question (*your duplicate*) has nothing in common with this question here. The duplicate will not helping someone to understand, that `$` and `$(this)` are totally different ... So as I said, this is not a duplicate of the question you marked here. @Rayon

Comment: @Rayon i dont want the difference but what is the usage and everything about $, this and $(this) and the duplicate answer does not have that.

Comment: @dilwaria – Your question does ask something about `"difference"`

Comment: @eisbehr – As you said, _"$(this) and this can be compared"_, Provided dupe has __8__ answers to highlight those differences.. [___This___](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3714581/1746830) is the closest solution IMO..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short (*assuming jQuery is included, of course*):

- `$` is a variable of `window` containering the jQuery library itself.
- `this` is a variable containing a DOM element.
- `$(this)` casts the element `this` to an jQuery object.

So basically you can't talk about a *difference*. The one is the whole library itself and the other is just using the library ...

Another example to be clear:

```
var $ = function(param) {};
var elem = this;

$        // the library
elem     // the element
$(elem); // the usage
```

Comment: Sir, what do you mean by variable of window , it means Dom only or what ?

Comment: `$` is the same as `window.$`, you can use both, it is the same. Globally registered variables are always a property of the `window` object. @dilwaria

Comment: _"$ is the variable of window containering the jQuery library itself."_ Little confusing... `$` is not variable(key) of window object unless `jQuery` is included..

Comment: Because the question is tagged `jQuery` and the question goes straight to `jQuery`, I'm pretty sure we can assume that we talking about using `jQuery`. ;) @Rayon

Comment: @eisbehr – Fair enough... But _"$ is the variable of window"_ That is for sure....