# jquery onclick - expanded answer on what $(this) returns in the generic case?

Tags: jquery

What is it that $(this) evaluates to if I call it on an onclick event, in jquery?

I'm really wanting a high-level conceptual example, i understand roughly what is going on but not what I should actually expect.

It's extremely possible this is duplicated elsewhere, but SO search didn't return anything for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this)

Comment: *but SO search didn't return anything for me* You should use Google Searh

Comment: Simply, this evaluates to event.target with is the target that triggered the event and $(this) wraps it in a jquery object to run jquery functions