# How do I call this function in other parts of my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pardon me if this is a very silly question. I'm brand new to JS and I was wondering how I can use this function in other parts of my code. I looked at tutorials and other websites, but the way they define functions seems to be different than what I have here. Could anyone please nudge me in the right direction?

```
$('.message_div').each(function message_function()
{
    console.log("One liner");
  var th = $(this);
  var ih = $(this).outerHeight(); // outer height
  var oh = $(this).find('.message').outerHeight(); 
    console.log("Oh", oh);
  var txt = $(this).find('.message').html(); 
    console.log("Ih", ih);



   if (oh > ih)
   {
       th.html('');
       th.html('<marquee class="message" direction="up" scrollamount="1" scrolldelay="0">' + txt + '</marquee>')
   }
});

//message_function(); -----> Is this the right way?
```

Comment: Declare the function as you learned in those tutorials, then you can both use it for jQuery (`$('.message_div').each(message_function)`) and call it from everywhere else

Comment: Define it as a function then call it by function name or add it directly as an event responde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several intricacies here with regards to what jQuery does. The simple way of referencing this function later on would be to store it in a variable:

```
function message_function()
{
    console.log("One liner");
    var th = $(this);
    //... (rest of function omitted for brevity)
}

$('.message_div').each(message_function);//note that the function handle is used here,
                                         //and not the result of the function which would
                                         //have used the () to call it

///and then later on
message_function();
```

However, the problem here is with `this`. jQuery will bind `this` behind the scenes (which means it works fine in `each`), however in order to properly call the message function separately, you would need to have an element ready to bind. For example,

```
var element = document.querySelector("div");
message_function.call(element);
```

alternatively:

```
var element = document.querySelector("div");
var elementMessage = message_function.bind(element);
elementMessage();
```

Here is a broader explanation of what `this` is, and how jQuery interacts with it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28443915/1026459

Answer (score 0):

Inside the same file :

- Move that code inside a function
- Call the function

Outside of that file :

- Move the function (you just created) to a `.js` file
- Include the `.js` file in the desired document
- Make sure the DOM elements properties match what's  in the script