# Rails 5: Submit form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ujs

I am trying to submit a form with jQuery if any of the element changes. For now I am not using `remote: true`.

Here is the code that renders the partial:

```
views/assets/index.html.erb
<%= render @assets %>
```

Code for partial:

```
views/assets/_asset.html.erb
<%= form_for [asset.project, asset] do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Following is the javascript code for form submit:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  if (!($(".assets.index").length > 0)) return;

  $('.edit_asset').change(function() {
    alert("submitting..");
    $(this).submit();
  });
});
```

It's doing the `alert` but form is not getting submitted, please suggest..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the issue was [$(this) vs this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this). So it should be

```
this.submit(); # or
$(this)[0].submit();
```

But client side validations on form elements like `required: true` won't work as it's bound to the submit button of the form. So we have to trigger that event, here is how I am doing it:

```
views/assets/_asset.html.erb
<%= form_for [asset.project, asset] do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit "Update", style: "display: none;" %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Javascript code will be:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  if (!($(".assets.index").length > 0)) return;

  jQuery.fn.submitOnChange = function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
      $(this).find("input[type=submit]").click();
    })
    return this;
  }
  $('.edit_asset').submitOnChange();
});
```

If we want to do this remotely, we have to add `remote: true` & `authenticity_token: true` to the `form_for`, so it will be:

```
<%= form_for([asset.project, asset], authenticity_token: true, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `$(this)` in the `.change` for `.edit_asset` is targeting that element and trying to submit it. You need to find the form object and submit that instead:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  if (!($(".assets.index").length > 0)) return;

  $('.edit_asset').change(function() {
    alert("submitting..");
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
  });
});
```

This could also be a bit stressful on your install, I'd recommend having a bit of a timeout after the changes and then submitting rather than constantly hammering your rails install with submit requests.

Comment: ah, my apologies. Have you tried a `debugger;` statement in the change to try and manually run the `$(this).submit()` ? It may be worth doing that to see the exact issue you're having. Worth noting too that with `remote: true` off you'll trigger a page refresh.

Comment: Not working as in how? Is there any response from it? No errors? Nothing? Does the form ever submit? Can you see it in the console etc?

Comment: Found the issue it should be this not $(this)