# Instead of using $(this) what else can I use?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code I want to edit:

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Instead of using `$(this)`, why can't I do the following:

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
    $('.tab').click(function().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

If that is never going to work, how can I recreate the initial code without having to use `$(this)`?

Comment: Question, why it is not working. What is the issue ?

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the specific one that triggered the function. `$('.tab')` refers to all of them.

Comment: Also, why do you have a `.click()` inside of a `.click()`?

Comment: I guess the true question is _why_ do you not want to use `$(this)` to get the jQuery object of the current scope element? This has a strong [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) smell.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `this`? Is there a reason you are trying to find a different way?

Comment: You can use `$(event.currentTarget)`.

Comment: Still curious why you dont want to use `this` @Disguy. also you should check an answer that worked. These people took their time to give you an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why you want to do this, but here is a way to avoid using "this".

```
$(".tab").click(function(ev){
    $(ev.currentTarget).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.tab')` refers to *all* elements with class="tab", `$(this)` refers to the *one* element with class="tab" that was just clicked.

For more information on `this` in jQuery, see [jQuery: What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28443915/1026459)