# in jQuery, use additional selector to $(this)

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function to return the values of checked checkboxes in a form:

```
$.fn.selected_values = function() {
    return $(this).map( function() { if( $(this).is(':checked') ) { return this.value; } } ).get().join(",");
};
```

I was wondering if there is a less cumbersome way to say "$this, plus another criteria". In other words, rather than using `if( $(this).is('checked'){...}` in a loop, is there some way to say something like `$(this):checked` ?  Then I could do something like:

```
$.fn.selected_values = function() {
    return $(this):checked.map( function() { return this.value; } ).get().join(",");
};
```

The existing code does work, but it seems that over time such a selector could result much more readable code.  Does it exist?

Comment: @gvmani: That's not the same.

Comment: What is the value of `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`filter` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), which filters a jQuery object to only include elements that match a selector.

Side note: Inside a jQuery method, `this` is already a jQuery object (just like any other class instance method); there is no reason to write `$(this)`.

Comment: this.filter(':checked') is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: For people reading this later, more info on `$(this)` vs. `this`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this

Answer (score 0):

Use [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector this way:

```
$('input.email_toggle:checked')
```

Comment: I'm trying to keep things as clean as possible for the end user. As "checked" is a part of the selector **by definition** when fetching values of selected items, I want it contained in the function itself.