# Retrieve The PHP variable Value of a HTMl Element Using Jquery inside a Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a strange problem. I am getting the table values using PHP MySQL using a while loop and stored them in a array. Then I am displaying it one after another in a single page.

```
    $sql = "select * from newsfeed order by id DESC";
$result = $db->query($sql);

$posts_array = array();  // Storing the result to an Custom Array
$index = 0;

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $posts_array[$index] = $row;
        $index++; 
    }
}
```

I have successfully set the $post_id of the posts on to the HTML elements using the following code.

```
    <?php 
                $array_size = sizeof($posts_array);
                for($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i++){
            ?>
            <div class='wrapper' id='wrapper'>
            <div class='user'>
<!-- Some Code -->
                <?php
                    $post_id = $posts_array[$i][id];
                 ?>
             <input type='image' name='like' id='like' width='40' height='40' src='like_btn.png' value='<?php echo ($post_id);'?> />

            <?php } ?>
```

Now I want to take that value using Jquery and do some Database Work. I have accessed the value using the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function justsomething() {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
</script>
```

The problem is I am only getting the last post's id as alert() for every post rather than getting different id's .
Please help me. I am confused whether the PHP script is loading every time I click and call the justsomething() function.

Note: I can display the $post_id of every post alone without any problem.

Comment: Please show the while loop.

Comment: <?php 
                $array_size = sizeof($posts_array);
                for($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i++){
}

Inside this Loop I have put the above codes. I have stored the results from fetch_assoc() into the array "$posts_array" and displaying it using this for loop.
 ?>

Comment: Are you creating the function inside the loop? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: How is the code in the comment related? Please show the mentioned while loop, which creates the values for `$post_id`. It looks like you'd have multiple `id`s with the same value, though. You shouldn't.

Comment: Don't put blobs of code in comments. Edit the question with formatted code

Comment: Added the Code with proper formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacuse the `id` should be unique to one html element try changing your code to this :

```
<?php $array_size = sizeof($posts_array); for($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i++){ ?>
<input type='image' name='like_<?php echo $i ?>' id='like_<?php echo $i ?>' width='40' height='40' src='like_btn.png' value='<?php echo $post_id;?>' onclick='justsomething(this);' />
<?php } ?>
<script>
function justsomething(el) {
    var img = el;
    alert(img.value);
}
</script>
```

here is an example

```js
function justsomething(el) {
    var img = el;
    alert(img.value);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='image' name='like_1' id='like_1' width='40' height='40' src='like_btn.png' value='15454' onclick='justsomething(this);' />
```

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: the clicked element [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this)

Comment: No it is not. `onclick` functions have no implicit `this`

Comment: @charlietfl see the answer the onclick attr send the element to the function

Comment: yes I have tried $(this).val() But it doesn't invoke the alert();

Comment: @HarishST see the example and change the javascript it is working now

Comment: @charlietfl is it you how down vote i was debuggin the code it is working now

Comment: Best to not post code that needs debugging for something as trivial as this

Comment: Upvoted! Thanks Everyone for taking your time to help me

Answer (score 0):

It works for loop, I hope You can make use of it

> $("input[id=like]").each(function(i){
>           alert($(this).val());
>       });

It will alert values from every `<input id="like"...`

Comment: Thanks . Surely  can make use of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
onclick='justsomething(this)'

function justsomething(obj) {
        alert($(obj).val());
    }
```

Comment: `this` is a reserved keyword

Comment: @Hasan llyas Thanks for the Answer.