# calling a function vs coding directly

Tags: jquery

I have this code for textarea autoheight

```
   function h(el) {
        $(el).height(el.scrollHeight);
    }

$('textarea').each(function () {
    h(this); //  works
    //$(this).height($(this).scrollHeight);  //  doesn't work
});

$('textarea').on('input', function () {
    h(this);  // works
    //$(this).height($(this).scrollHeight);  //  dosen't work
});
```

If I replace `h(this)` with commented lines - they doesn't work.
What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your group that doesn't work, you are converting `this` to jQuery both on .height and .scrollHeight, but in your function `h`, you only convert the el to jQuery on `height`

```
$('textarea').each(function () {
    $(this).height(this.scrollHeight);
});
```

Comment: What does "Converting a component to jQuery" mean?

Comment: @EmreTapcı - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this