# Wrap all text that starts with a certain word

Tags: jquery

I'm programming a social media engine and I'd like to use jQuery to automatically wrap all http and https links into an `<a>` element.

This is what I've gotten to after a lot of Google searching:

```
$('*').each(function test() {
    var str = $(this);
    if(str.match("^http")) {
        str.wrap("<a></a>");
    }
});
```

But when I run the code, I get the following error in the log.

```
TypeError: str.match is not a function [Learn More]
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: `$(this)` would be an element not a text.

Comment: `str` is not a string.  It's a jQuery object.  Did you check https://api.jquery.com/ to see if `match()` is an existing method?

Comment: Can you show a representative sample of the HTML you're working with, including examples of the text (as an input/'before') and show the result you're hoping to create (the output/'after')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly wasn't specific with my question the first time around, but I managed to get my answer regardless.

```
$('.content').html($('.content').html().replace(/@([^\s]+)/g,'<a href="$1">@$1</a>'));
```

This will wrap all code starting with "@" in an  element.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, JavaScript's [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) operates on a string and `$(this)` is a jQuery object, not a string. See [What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this)

I suggest testing `match()` against the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) content of the element.
If it starts with "http", wrap the element with an `<a>` with its `href` set to the text content.

```js
$('span,p').each(function() {
  var $str = $(this);
  var text = $str.text();
  if (text.match("^http")) {
    var $link = $("<a>", {
      'href': text
    });
    $str.wrap($link);
  }
});
```

```css
span,
p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>http://google.com</span>
<span>file://host/path</span>
<p>https://stackoverflow.com</p>
<p>Something Else</p>
```