# Changing Form Attributes Before Submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm working on something that involves ensuring the method of form submission is POST not GET when the method might have been omitted somehow and somewhere. A JS/jQuery function checks each form before submission for a particular class. If the class exists, it goes on to check the method. If the method is a GET, it should ignore it and submit the form. But if it is undefined or empty, it should proceed to set the method to POST then submit. 
This is the JQuery used. The HTML follows.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('form').submit(function() {
        if (this.find(':submit').is('.ckh-method')) {
          if ((this.attr('method') !== "GET" && this.attr('method') == "") || this.attr('method') == undefined) {
            this.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
            return true;
          }
        }
      })
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fontawesome-free/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="phpFile.php" method="">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"> 
           <i class="fa fa-user-alt"></i>
        </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" required="required" value=''>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"> 
          <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
        </span>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" required="required" value=''>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="conditions col-sm-12"><a href="anotherPage.html">Forgot Username or Password?</a>
          <div class="text-center col-sm-12 error"></div>
        </p>
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="btn-hold">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success  btn-block ckh-method">Log In</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-block" href="proceed.php">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Problem: The form method doesn't change on submission because there is a JS error somewhere in my code. I'm suspecting it has to do with the 'this' keyword. Maybe I used it wrongly. I've tried setting breakpoints so I can identify the issue but the form submits before I can step into the function (in my Developer's tool) and discover the problem. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Use `$(this)` instead of `this`. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this

Comment: You can create a function and cell it on submit button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found your console error. `bootstrap js requires jquery` so i have corrected the sequence as below

> first : Jquery JS
>
> second : Bootstrap JS
>
> also use $(this) instead of just this
>
> use attr for setting attributes instead of setAttribute

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
        if ($(this).find(':submit').is('.ckh-method')) 
        {debugger;
            if (($(this).attr('method') !== "GET" && $(this).attr('method') == "") || $(this).attr('method') == undefined) {
                $(this).attr('method', 'POST');
                return true;
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fontawesome-free/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="phpFile.php" method="">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"> 
           <i class="fa fa-user-alt"></i>
        </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" required="required" value=''>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"> 
          <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
        </span>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" required="required" value=''>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="conditions col-sm-12"><a href="anotherPage.html">Forgot Username or Password?</a>
                    <div class="text-center col-sm-12 error"></div>
                </p>
                <div class="col-sm-12" id="btn-hold">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success  btn-block ckh-method">Log In</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-block" href="proceed.php">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
        </form>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please check answer i have few changes

Answer (score 1):

```js
var frm = document.getElementById("form1")
frm.addEventListener("submit" ,checkmethod )

function checkmethod(event){
    event.preventDefault();
   if(frm.method !="GET") frm.method = "POST";
   frm.submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="" >

    <button type="submit">submit</button>

 </form>
```

Comment: Don't want the form attribute, on submit to be in the HTML. Want the entire procedure as client-hidden as JS can get.

Comment: it is now run from js file

Answer (score 0):

I edited the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready({
  $('form').submit(function() {
    if ($(this).find(':submit').is('.chk-method')) {
      if (($(this).attr('method') !== "GET" && $(this).attr('method') == "") || $(this).attr('method') == undefined) {
        $(this).attr('method', 'POST');
        return true;
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Use $(this) instead of 'this' and attr() instead of setAttribute().

Comment: You don't have to do the modification when the form is submitted though. You may do it when the document is ready and the form will have the submit attribute you want.

Comment: @AliBARIN With document ready, any changes made to the form somehow after loading would not take effect, say changing your method from POST or nothing after loading the document. It is **important** that it is done before submission