# When click dropdown other dropdown should hide

Tags: jquery, html

When I click on dropdown that opening without prpblem but if i click other dropdown both dropdown are open i want to do when click dropdown that should be open other open dropdown should hide.

```
<div class="more-options" id="PostMenu<?php echo $p_id; ?>" onclick="openMenu(<?php echo $p_id; ?>)">
<img src="../images/ellipsis-h-solid.svg" alt="">

<div class="user-setting-drop" id="openDropMenu<?php echo $p_id; ?>">
<a href="#" title="">Report</a>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

            function openMenu(y){
                //alert(001);
                    $('#PostMenu'+y).on('click', function () {
                        $('#openDropMenu'+y).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                        return false;
                    });
            }
          </script>
```

Comment: Which library you are using for dropdown?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Natively it hides the dropdown when you open second one, you can create snippet by editing your question and show us the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With jQuery You Can...

- determine what tag was clicked by using [`$(this)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1051782/2813224) or [`e.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)
- delegate/register events on multiple tags with [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) -- no need to use [onevent attributes like `onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)
- reference any [jQuery Object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) with a simple variable

---

### Explination

If you have multiple tags that need to be registered/delegated to an event, use `.class` or `<tagName>` -- using `#id` is arduous and unnecessary.

```
$('.more-options').on('click', function() {...
```

Use `$(this)` to reference the clicked tag and chain [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to reference it's descendants if needed. If a line gets too unwieldy, store it in a variable.

```
var clicked = $(this).find('.user-setting-drop');
```

When you want *"accordion behavior"*, close/deactivate/collapse all tags (excluding the clicked tag by using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)), then open/activate/expand the clicked tag.

```
$('.user-setting-drop').not(clicked).removeClass('active'); 
clicked.toggleClass('active');
```

---

### Demo 1

**Uses [`.remove`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)/[`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toogleclass/) methods. It involves more work with CSS if you want some animation.**

```js
$('.more-options').on('click', function() {
  var clicked = $(this).find('.user-setting-drop');
  $('.user-setting-drop').not(clicked).removeClass('active');
  clicked.toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.more-options {
  cursor: pointer
}

.user-setting-drop {
  max-height: 0;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.active {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 5000px;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s, max-height: 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">

<div class="more-options" id="PostMenu0">
  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  <div class="user-setting-drop" id="openDropMenu0">
    <a href="#/" title="">Report</a>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="more-options" id="PostMenu1">
  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  <div class="user-setting-drop" id="openDropMenu1">
    <a href="#/" title="">Report</a>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="more-options" id="PostMenu2">
  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  <div class="user-setting-drop" id="openDropMenu2">
    <a href="#/" title="">Report</a>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Demo 2

**Uses [`.slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)/[`Up()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) methods. It involves less work with animation already built in.**

```js
$('.more-options').on('click', function() {
  var clicked = $(this).find('.user-setting-drop');
  $('.user-setting-drop').not(clicked).slideUp(300);
  clicked.slideToggle(500);
});
```

```css
.more-options {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.user-setting-drop {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">

<div class="more-options" id="PostMenu0">
  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  <div class="user-setting-drop" id="openDropMenu0">
    <a href="#/" title="">Report</a>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="more-options" id="PostMenu1">
  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  <div class="user-setting-drop" id="openDropMenu1">
    <a href="#/" title="">Report</a>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="more-options" id="PostMenu2">
  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  <div class="user-setting-drop" id="openDropMenu2">
    <a href="#/" title="">Report</a>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```