# How jQuery handle 'this' in the array function?

Tags: jquery

I am very new in jQuery. I wrote a code

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        a= $( '.play' ).click( function() {
                let a = this;
                a.css( 'background-image', 'url(pause.svg)' );
                return a;
        } );
)};
```

Then when I console `a`, I get the correct result also `a.css` is referring to jQuery.
but when i clicking on the element a type-error returned.

> TypeError: a.css is not a function

Maybe I am not yet properly understand async JavaScript call. My question is, why I am getting this error? How jQuery handle **this** keyword in to the Array Function?

--- Problem Solved ---

I found [this vs $(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this) discussion is my answer.

Comment: it should be `let a = $(this);`

Comment: Yha, it works. How?

Comment: I suggest you   console.log(this)  then you will understand how this object works. It points to current execution. It has all the information of that element.

Answer (score 2):

```
let a = this;
```

needs to be

```
let a = $(this); // now it will create an object of current click element.
```

I think below code will work perfectly as well,try it.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $( '.play' ).click( function() {
        $(this).css( 'background-image', 'url(pause.svg)' );
    });
)};
```

Note: `this` refer to a javascript object and work in a different manner.For more details read below links(regarding what it is, how it works based on different mode and way of calling)

[javascript this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

[this vs $(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this)

Answer (score 1):

you just need to understand basic.

```
this -> Html DOM element. //the classic JavaScript API is exposed here
$(this)-> $() + this -> you are passing element in a jQuery Constructor-> JQuery object. // jQuery API is exposed
```

So when you do that you are enabling jQuery Object so you can play with it.