# How to return a wrapper Object instead of HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor

I am writing a micro-library instead of using jQuery. I need only 3-4 methods ( for DOM traversal, Adding Eventlisteners etc). So I decided to write them myself instead of bloating the site with jQuery.

Here is the snippet from the code:

`lib.js`

```js
window.twentyFourJS = (function() {

    let elements;

    const Constructor = function(selector) {
        elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        this.elements = elements;
    };

    Constructor.prototype.addClass = function(className) {
        elements.forEach( item => item.classList.add(className));
        return this;
    };

    Constructor.prototype.on = function(event, callback, useCapture = false){
        elements.forEach((element) => {
            element.addEventListener(event, callback, useCapture);
        });
        return this;
    }

  const initFunction = function(selector){
        return new Constructor(selector);
    }
    
    return initFunction;
    
})(twentyFourJS);
```

`script.js`

```js
(function($){

  $('.tab-menu li a').on('click', function(event) {

    console.log('I am clicked'); // This works
    
    this.addClass('MyClass'); // This does NOT work (as expected)

    // I want to be able to do this
    $(this).addClass('MyClass');

    event.preventDefault();

  });
})(twentyFourJS);
```

Basically I want to be able to use `$(this)` like we use it in jQuery.

`this.addClass('MyClass')` and `$(this).addClass('MyClass')` won't work and this is the expected behaviour.

As per my understanding `this` is referring to the plain HTML element. So it does not have access to any Constructor methods. it won't work.

And I have not written any code that will wrap element in Constructor object in `$(this)`. I will have to do some changes to my `Constructor` so that I can access the Constructor functions using `$(this)`. What are those changes/addition to it?

Kindly recommend only Vanilla JS ways instead of libraries.

Comment: so in your constructor you need to see if it is a string or if it is an object....

Comment: You already use `jquery` (Under `script.js`) - So your question is a bit confusing (Jquery already have this ideas). In general start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/whats-the-difference-between-this-and-this

Comment: @EzraSiton I am not using jQuery. The code style just looks like it.

Comment: @epascarello Basically I want to be able to use `$(this)` like we use it in jQuery.

Comment: I understand that is what I said in my comment and in my answer.

Comment: Note that your current code has a huge bug. (Even without `on`.) Because the `elements` variable is shared between different instances of `twentyFourJS` The following does not what you expect: `const $a = $(".a")` then `const $b = $(".b")` then `$a.addClass("c")`. This does **not** add "c" to the elements with the class "a", but adds it to the elements with class "b". Because the second initialisation will reassign the `elements` variable. Remove the variable and only use `this.elements` which is unique for each instance.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thanks for pointing out. That prevents from a big debugging in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your constructor you need to see what you have and handle it in different ways.

```
const Constructor = function(selector) {
    if (typeof selector === 'string') {
        elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    } else {
      // need some sort of check to see if collection or single element
      // This could be improved since it could fail when someone would add a length property/attribute
      elements = selector.length ? selector : [selector]; 
    }
    this.elements = elements;
};
```

Comment: Alternative you could also use `"forEach" in selector` instead of `selector.length`. `forEach` seems to be the only method used. In some scenarios `length` is not present while `forEach` is. An example would be if you pass a Set instance, which uses `size` instead of `length`. - This also solves empty array passing. Which in this solution would nest the array. If `selector` is `[]`, then `elements` will be `[[]]` (because `0` is falsy). Resulting in errors if you then call `.addClass("a")`.

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is make sure your `Constructor` argument can distinguish between a string selector being passed in, and an object.

```
const Constructor = function(selector) {
  if(typeof selector == "string"){
    elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    this.elements = elements;
  }
  else{
    this.elements = selector;
  }
};
```

You can go further than this, but at a very minimum for the example given that works.

Live example below:

```js
window.twentyFourJS = (function() {

    let elements;

    const Constructor = function(selector) {
      if(typeof selector == "string"){
        elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        this.elements = elements;
      }
      else{
        this.elements = selector;
      }
    };

    Constructor.prototype.addClass = function(className) {
        elements.forEach( item => item.classList.add(className));
        return this;
    };

    Constructor.prototype.on = function(event, callback, useCapture = false){
        elements.forEach((element) => {
            element.addEventListener(event, callback, useCapture);
        });
        return this;
    }

  const initFunction = function(selector){
        return new Constructor(selector);
    }
    
    return initFunction;
    
})();


(function($){

  $('.btn').on('click', function(event) {

    console.log('I am clicked'); // This works
    
    // I want to be able to do this
    $(this).addClass('MyClass');

    event.preventDefault();

  });
})(twentyFourJS);
```

```css
.MyClass{
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click me</btn>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. first You Need to Check for a string
   case 1. $("div")
2. Then You need to Check for it's NodeType and for a window

case 1. var elm = document .getElementById("ID")
$(elm)
case 2. $(this) -- window

```
function $(selector){
var element; 
 if (typeof selector === 'string') {
element = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
}
if (element.nodeType || element=== window) element= [selector];

return element ; 
}
```